# Repeated Substitution or Telescoping to figure out running time complexity from a function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Use repeated substitution (or telescoping) to determine the asymptotic upper bound for the running time of an algorithm defined by the recurrence relation below:

```
f(n) = 4f(n/2) + g(n) with g(n) ∈ Θ(n) and f(1) ∈ Θ(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's Theta(n^2). Consider using the master theorem. Or, alternatively, draw the recursion tree. You will see you have n^log4 leaves

Comment: Can you please show me how do we proceed with telescoping to solve this?